# Retrieving coordinates of PDF graphical elements with PDFSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I actually asked this question already [Extract graphical Elements and its coordinate from PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296898/extract-graphical-elements-and-its-coordinate-from-pdf) but I was supposed to write the project in **Java**.... unfortunately there is no function for this. Plse see the link. I was wondering if **PDFSharp** has the feature of extracting the coordinats of the graphical elements such as rectangle or so.

Comment: If it was for iText, I might be interested... ;)

Comment: I just wanted to avoid to enhance itext as u said... it is a lot of work I guess but I reckon I have to do it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDFsharp can open and modify PDF files, but it cannot display them and it does not provide access to elements of a page.

Finding the co-ordinates where elements are drawn is not a simple task as transformations may apply to the drawing instructions. I never used iText so I don't know if it can do it. PDFsharp can not.

PDFsharp cannot render PDF files. If it could easily determine the co-ordinates of graphical objects, it could easily render PDF files.